# Lower Navigation text while using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap for a navigation bar. I want the navigation text to be lower on the navigation (currently it's close to the top of the page).
[picture of navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A02WI.png). Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right sidebar">
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="projectLink">samples &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="aboutLink">services &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="blogLink">tweets &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="contactLink" class="mail" onclick="openForm()">contact</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Any tips are appreciated so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `padding-top: 40px;` inside your `navbar-nav` class.
Obs.: Edit 40px for the height you want.

Or simple use a Navbar from Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#text

Comment: @Dani glad my comment helped you. Feel free to make this post closed by selecting my answer.